# MCMC algorithm overestimating the mode

Tags: distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am looking for an MCMC algorithm that leaves a target $\pi$ **invariant** but that overestimates the mode.

Basically I am looking for an algorithm that whose transition kernel leaves $\pi$ stationary (can be either reversible or non-reversible) but that **mixes poorly** in the sense that it tends to spend too much time on the mode rather than the tails.

Do you know of any such method? Intuitively I was thinking that some **gradient-based** algorithm could do the job. However HMC mixes very well of course. I know this is an odd question!

Comment: Why you need it? Context would be helpful.

Comment: @Tim basically because I have a kernel $K_{\text{under}}$ that leaves $\pi$ invariant but underestimates the mode. I would like to find another kernel $K_{\text{over}}$ that overestimates the mode while leaving $\pi$ invariant. My hope is that 
$$
K_{\text{cycle}} = K_{\text{under}} K_{\text{over}}
$$ or 
$$
K_{\text{mixture}} = \alpha K_{\text{under}} + (1 - \alpha) K_{\text{over}} \qquad \alpha\in[0, 1]
$$ would mix quite well, or at least better than $K_{\text{under}}$ alone.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want? By definition, if the algorithm spends "too much time in the mode" it won't have the posterior as its stationary distribution. It's easy to come up with settings where you end up in the mode for an extremely long time, then move to the tail and get stuck there for an extremely long time, but the fact that the posterior is stationary means that you get stuck in each part for exactly the correct amount of time in the long run.

Comment: @guy I will clarify. I am looking for an algorithm that leaves $\pi$ invariant. So yes, if you let the algorithm run for a very long time, it will eventually produce good samples. What I am looking for, however, is an algorithm that leaves $\pi$ invariant but that has the tendency (for a not so large number of iterations) to overestimate the mode. 

As an unrelated example, consider a Gibbs sampler for a highly correlated 2D Normal. You can define Gibbs so that it leaves the 2D Normal invariant yet, in a not-so-large number of iterations it will mix very poorly and explore only 1 mode.

Comment: Of course, the Gibbs example above is different from what I am looking for, however it shows that although there are many algorithms that leave a distribution invariant, each will have some pros and cons in a finite number of iterations

Comment: For instance could it be that a MALA algorithm with a quite large step size will tend to overestimate modes in a finite (and not too large) number of iterations? My intuition tells me that gradient-based methods might consistently overestimate the mode in the short-run

Comment: My point is that most natural algorithms which "overestimates the mode" in the short-run will also "underestimate the mode" it in the short-run as well, depending on where you start the chain. That must be the case, because otherwise the stationary distribution would have to be wrong. So you can't design an algorithm which overshoots on the mode by design without introducing the exact same behavior in the tails. Composing two chains with the same flaw probably won't give any progress on your problem.

Comment: A MALA is attracted by the mode due to its gradient component but unless there are several modes that are far away from each other and the energy of the MALA is low, the chain will eventually explore all modes.